# Hive: Covert String to Boolean

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hql

I have two HIVE tables and I need to convert *String* column from *table 1* to *Boolean* column to *table 2*. The only function what I found is CAST but it works only in case the input is numeric value. For example this return "false" what is correct:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS BOOLEAN); # Result is true
```

But my source is STRING column which consist values as "false" and then the *cast* function return the following result what is not correct for me:

```
SELECT CAST("false" AS BOOLEAN); # Result is true
```

Please do you know other way how to convert STRING column into BOOLEAN column in HIVE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a little workaround but it works. i used the *case* function. The sample:

```
# Create TMP_TABLE1
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  my_db.TMP_TABLE1
(   
    bool_val_str STRING
);

# Create TMP_TABLE2
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  my_db.TMP_TABLE2
(   
    bool_val_bool BOOLEAN
);

# Insert values into TMP_TABLE1
INSERT INTO my_db.TMP_TABLE1 VALUES ("false"),("False"),("FALSE"),("true"),("True"),("TRUE");

# ===========================================================
# THE CONVERSION IS HERE:
# Insert values into TMP_TABLE2 with conversion to boolean
# ===========================================================
INSERT INTO my_db.TMP_TABLE2 
(
    bool_val_bool
) 
    SELECT 
        CASE lower(bool_val_str) WHEN "true" THEN true WHEN "false" THEN false ELSE NULL END
    FROM 
         my_db.TMP_TABLE1;
```

Comment: Hi, when trying this i get the following: 
`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 2:30 Argument type mismatch 'true': The expressions after WHEN should have the same type with that after CASE: "string" is expected but "boolean" is found`
Do you know the workaround to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot cast a string into boolean but you can cast boolean to string (like true -> '1'; false -> '0'). You can also use if clause if you want.

```
select if(lower(bool_val_str)='true', true, false) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workarround I would propose to directly use a CASE to convert the string to the boolean we want:

CASE column
    WHEN 'True' THEN true
    WHEN 'False' THEN false
    ELSE NULL END column